how to make list scrollable inside singlechildscroll view in flutter?
I have a wrapper class with nested bottom navigation bar and singlechildscroll view and list inside one of the nested class is not getting scrolled.
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 883,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      
                SizedBox(
                  height: 660,
                  child: IndexedStack(
                    index: _selectedIndex,
                    children: [
                      HomeScreen(
                        globalKey: bottomNavigatorKey,
                      ),
                      const ProjectNavigator(),
                      const BookNavigator(),
                      const CartNavigator()
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          
          unselectedItemColor: AppColor.blue,
          key: bottomNavigatorKey,

          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          selectedItemColor: AppColor.red,
          selectedIconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: AppColor.red),

          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.description,
              ),
              label: 'Project',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.book,
              ),
              label: 'Books',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
              ),
              label: 'Cart',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

I tried customScroolview for mainwrapper class but that is also not working.Any Idea how to resolve this issue.

you can remove the fixed height height: 883 it will be scroll-able. Also I would suggest using controllable inside each   IndexedStack's children  based on demand

remove your fixed height

Why bottomNavigationBar is inside SingleChildScrollView?

Remove SingleChildScrollView and fixed height and add SingleChildScrollView on each child

After removing fixed height it's working now

Flexible(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            HomeScreen(
              globalKey: bottomNavigatorKey,
            ),
            const ProjectNavigator(),
            const BookNavigator(),
            const CartNavigator()
          ],
        ),
      )

try using this instead of this
SizedBox(
                  height: 660,
                  child: IndexedStack(
                    index: _selectedIndex,
                    children: [
                      HomeScreen(
                        globalKey: bottomNavigatorKey,
                      ),
                      const ProjectNavigator(),
                      const BookNavigator(),
                      const CartNavigator()
                    ],
                  ),
                )

Maybe fixed height restrict the scroll. Hope it will help you.
